# Document app's to generate documents

Tags: app, contracts

Buddies,

I'm looking for an app that allow me to manage the document creation process inside salesforce.com. I'd already try Conga Composer and S-Docs but, to fit my needs, it's important to user be able to edit the text after the template merge process and before the print process.
Can someone suggest me some other alternative?

Best regards,

Saulo

Comment: Just a 2 cents on Conga, conga has been my personal favorite so far for such reqs because  1) it's simple UI and usage 2) awesome support

Answer (score 0):

take a look at drawloop. i'm not positive about post creation editing so make sure to inquire about that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer m.fulton. I've already seen drawloop but it don't fit to my needs too.

Comment: Then you should update your question to reflect that. You list solutions you've tried and do not include drawloop.

Answer (score 0):

Great question!  I work at Conga and have worked with quite a few customers to account for this requirement.  If your workflow is to create and download a merged document, make changes to the doc, and then print it, then this is what I would suggest:

1) Use Conga Composer to merge your document and ensure that you're using a Microsoft Word template.  Configure your merge process to keep the file in Word format (this is the default setting).

2) After using Composer to download the file, simply edit the file in Word just like a normal document.

3) Once you've made your changes, print the doc.

Does that type of workflow meet your needs?  There are some other AppExchange apps that allow you to edit documents post-merge (Contractually, for example) but I've found that they're not really geared towards printing.

I hope this helps!